# datetimepickers to check current time

Tags: .net, time, datetimepicker, intervals

I have two datetimepicker and 3 labels It looks like this

[image]

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim currentTime As TimeSpan = Date.Now.TimeOfDay

    If DateTimePicker1.Value <= Date.Now And Date.Now <= DateTimePicker2.Value Then
        Label3.Text = "In range"
    Else
        Label3.Text = "Not in range"
    End If
End Sub
```

I found the way to check if the time from datetimepickers are in range with current time.

How can i know how much time left before end and how much passed from start ?

I hope you understood.

Edit done:

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        lblnow.Text = Date.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")
        Dim currentTime As TimeSpan = Date.Now.TimeOfDay
        Dim starttime As TimeSpan = DateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay
        Dim endtime As TimeSpan = DateTimePicker2.Value.TimeOfDay

        If DateTimePicker1.Value <= Date.Now And Date.Now <= DateTimePicker2.Value Then
            Label3.Text = "In range"
            timeLeft.Text = endtime.Subtract(currentTime).ToString
            timePassed.Text = currentTime.Subtract(starttime).ToString
        Else
            Label3.Text = "Not in range"
        End If
    End Sub
```

How to not show miliseconds in this format

Answer (score 0):

U can use String.Remove

Reference: [String.Remove()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim starttime As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim endtime As Date = DateTimePicker2.Value

    Dim tmleft As TimeSpan = endtime.Subtract(Now)
    Dim tmPassed As TimeSpan = Now.Subtract(starttime)

    timeLeft.Text = tmleft.ToString.Remove(tmleft.ToString.IndexOf("."))
    timePassed.Text = tmPassed.ToString.Remove(tmPassed.ToString.IndexOf("."))
End Sub
```